# Как получить значение переменной из метода(конструктора) java

Tags: java, setter

Проблема. Есть 2 сеттера, и есть конструктор, в нем 2 аргумента (waterAmount, coffeeAmount) поля таким названием есть так-же в классе. И при попытке сделать `setWaterAmount(waterAmount);` выбирает переменную не из метода(конструктора) а из класса.

Возникает следующая ошибка:

> The method setCoffeeAmount(short) in the type CoffeeMachine is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Код:

```
package com.company;

public class CoffeeMachine {
    private final int maxWaterAmount = 4;
    private final int maxCoffeeAmount = 1000;
    private byte waterFill = 0;
    private short coffeeAmount = 0;
    public byte getWaterFill() {
        return waterFill;
    }
    public void setWaterFill(byte waterFill) {
        if (waterFill <= maxWaterAmount) {
            this.waterFill = waterFill;
        } else {
            this.waterFill = maxWaterAmount;
        }
    }
    public short getCoffeeAmount() {
        return coffeeAmount;
    }
    public void setCoffeeAmount(short coffeeAmount) {
        if (coffeeAmount <= maxCoffeeAmount) {
            this.coffeeAmount = coffeeAmount;
        } else {
            this.coffeeAmount = maxCoffeeAmount;
        }
    }
    public CoffeeMachine(int waterFill, int coffeeAmount) {
        setCoffeeAmount(coffeeAmount);//ошибка
        setWaterFill(waterFill);//ошибка
    }
    public CoffeeMachine() {}
    public String printCoffeeMachineData() {
        return "water amount is: "+waterFill+"l "+"coffee amount is: "+coffeeAmount+"g";
    }
    public String printCoffeeMachine() {
        return "water amount is: "+waterFill+"l "+"coffee amount is: "+coffeeAmount+"g";
    }
}
```

Comment: Да пожалуйста..

Comment: Еще бы увидеть код, который обращается к `CoffeeMachine` и демонстрирует проблему. Пока все выглядит нормально.

Comment: Посмотрите на конструктор `CoffeeMachine`

Comment: Ошибка? Укажите тогда сообщение об ошибке. Судя по всему проблема не с областью видимости переменных.

Comment: Прочитайте _"выбирает переменную не из метода(конструктора) а из класса. "_

Comment: The method setCoffeeAmount(short) in the type CoffeeMachine is not applicable for the arguments (int)

Comment: Проблема решилась кастом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это ошибка несоответствия типов.

Конструктор принимает переменную `int`

```
public CoffeeMachine(int waterFill, int coffeeAmount) {
```

, а `setCoffeeAmount` переменную типа `short`:

```
public void setCoffeeAmount(short coffeeAmount) {
```

Преобразование из `int` к `short` потенциально ведет к потере информации (если например значение не вмещается в `short`), о чем компилятор и предупреждает.

Либо приведите конструктор в соответствие с методами:

```
 public CoffeeMachine(byte waterFill, short coffeeAmount) {
```

либо методы и поля в соответствие с конструктором:

```
 private int coffeeAmount = 0;
 public void setCoffeeAmount(int coffeeAmount) {
```

либо приведите типы явно:

```
 setCoffeeAmount((short) coffeeAmount);
```

Последний вариант может привести к потере данных если значение в конструкторе выйдет [за рамки `short`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Short.html#MAX_VALUE). Например, если передать в конструктор 32769.

Answer (score 3):

Зачем в конструкторе пользоваться сеттером? Он там не нужен. Надо сразу в конструкторе писать

```
this.waterAmount = waterAmount;
this.coffeeAmount = coffeeAmount;
```

из своего комментария под ответом)):

> Однако проблема тут как минимум в том, что типы различаются. И передаешь ты `int`, а сеттер у тебя `short`, что совпадает с полем класса

Поэтому и проблему надо решать, основываясь на этом.

Comment: И что ты думаешь мне надо постоянно так писать `if (coffeeAmount <= maxCoffeeAmount) {
            this.coffeeAmount = coffeeAmount;
        } else {
            this.coffeeAmount = maxCoffeeAmount;
        }`

Comment: это же костыль.

Comment: @Duoxx в таком случае тебе нужно по-другому действовать. А то что ты делаешь - это и есть костыль. Однако проблема тут как минимум в том, что типы различаются. и передаешь ты int, а сеттер у тебя short, что совпадает с полем класса

Comment: А точно можно прикастить

Comment: @Duoxx при касте могут быть проблемы (потеря данных). однако ты тут сам уж должен решать, что именно тебе нужно

Answer (score 1):

Класс неверно спроектирован, потому что одно и то же поле `coffeeAmount` в разных местах используется с разным типом данных.

Ошибка несоответствия типов в сигнатурах:

```
public void setCoffeeAmount(short coffeeAmount) {
```

и

```
public CoffeeMachine(int waterFill, int coffeeAmount) {
```

Предлагаю стандартную последовательность действий:

1. Убрать костыли из класса и привести поля и к единым типам данных в полях, конструкторах, геттерах и сеттерах.
2. Сделать типовые конструкторы с такими же типами данных, как и у полей класса.
3. Если есть необходимость, то сделать "расширенные" конструкторы, то есть конструкторы, которые принимают на вход другие типы данных и выполняют явное или неявное преобразование входящих параметров к стандартными полям класса. В случае ошибок конвертации, эти конструкторы должен выдавать соответствующие Exceptions.